# Apache 2.4: Differences between prefork, event and worker modes

Tags: apache-2.4, worker-process, prefork

Apache 2.4.x [allows 3 different modes](http://www.slideshare.net/jimjag/httpd-cloudkillerapp):

- prefork
- event
- worker

What are the conceptual differences between these three? What are the types of applications or each or situations in which each MPM is useful?

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I am interested in the CONCEPTUAL differences between these. The other question is basically about asking for a recommendation...I have removed the "bonus question" i.e. request for recommendation to eliminate any possible overlap.

Comment: The conceptual differences are covered in that question; prefork creates forked processes which requests are dispatched to, worker runs a thread per connection, and event optimizes worker's threading by handling kept-alive connections centrally and dispatching to threads for each individual request from a connection.  If those aren't the kind of conceptual differences you're looking for, can you clarify what information you need?  We can definitely re-open this question if that information isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Thanks for that. That's definitely part of it. However, I was really looking for more than a one-liner for each...including a short explanation/primer of how each works...server received a request, what happens next,...including what are the advantages/disadvantages of processes vs threads, etc...including what sort of use case each is appropriate for, and bad for...if event just optimized worker and were just unquestionably "better", then Apache wouldn't really have a reason to provide the option, would it?

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).